# How to create 3 media queries. One for mobile,one for tablet and one for full width

Tags: php, css, wordpress, media-queries

I have a site I'm working on ( below ) and the problem is this:

The top menu does not lay out correctly when viewed in tablet devices. It kind of folds under itself.

I figure an easy way to correct this would to simply create a media query for the respective dimensions that the problem occurs,  and then to modify the css of the 'tablet.css' media query stylesheet to change the top menu.

Anyway, I can't seem to get the media query to function *in between* the mobile media query and full-screen css. In short **I can only get two css style-sheets toggling between one another at a time.**

Here is the site:
http://projectplay.staging.wpengine.com/

It's a WordPress instance which is written in PHP. Below is the header code with my two currently working media query attempts. I omitted my tablet attempt.

```
   <link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo bloginfo('stylesheet_url') ?>' media="only screen and (min-width: 480px)"/>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo TMM_THEME_URI; ?>/css/mobile.css' media="only screen and (max-width: 480px)">
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo TMM_THEME_URI; ?>/css/custom1.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo TMM_THEME_URI; ?>/css/custom2.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo TMM_THEME_URI; ?>/css/skeleton.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries. In these examples the `max-width:` determines when the custom css will show up. There is also `min-width` which can be used along `max-width` to target for specific size ranges.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px)" href="example.css" />
```

or in your CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
 .facet_sidebar {
  display: none;
 }
```

Comment: Would you mind telling me how you found the .facet_sidebar class. When using Chrome dev tools I did not see this displayed.

Comment: @TaoistWA, those two examples were taken from the link I posted, and aren't related to your code. You'll have to fill in the blanks to make it work with your code.